# Get monotonically increasing time that does not depend on time changes

Tags: java, linux, windows, time

I have a manager application that can maintain reserve state for some time for another application which has been closed. Manager application used `System.nanoTime()` to calculate reserve time, but now I need to save and restore state for this manager application (e.g. save and restore sessions in reserve and calculate time again), thus `System.nanoTime()` is not suitable anymore: it's not a good idea to summarize `System.nanoTime()` between JVM\PC reboots to maintain global timeline.
So I switched to `RuntimeMXBean` and it's `getUptime()` method for this purpose. But now I have another trouble: the time my manager application is down, there's no way to know for how long it is down. Hence if I have, for example, reserve for 60 minutes, app will be reservd for 60 minutes if manager application is up and running. And if I shut down my PC for 10 minutes, these 10 minutes will be lost and when I run manager application again, it will restore its state and count reserve as 60 minutes.
I'm looking for the way to know time since some point in the past until current time which cannot be modified by changing system or BIOS clock. Important note: manager application does not have access to web, so I can't use NTP.
Is there some ways to do that?

Comment: Can you install hardware that gets the time from an atomic clock radio broadcast? In the United States, that would be WWVB in Fort Collins, CO. [This model](https://www.meinberg-usa.com/products/usb-radio-clocks/wwvb-usb-radio-clock.htm) connects via USB. There are expansion card versions.

Comment: Or hardware that gets time from GPS or other GNSS? https://www.masterclock.com/products/pc-cards/pcie-gps

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately I can't to this

Answer (score 0):

You should store two information: 1) system time (your bios time if if you can't connect to a time server) and 2) reservation expiration.

This way the method that checks if the reservation has expired will get the current time and compare it against the saved time and expiration.

Comment: Can BIOS time be affected by user changing time in OS or BIOS directly? I store information about uptime of my manager application and I store another info to calculate reserve, there's no problem. The problem is if I use System.currentTimeMillis(), user can move forward his time and reserve will be lost. And System.nanoTime() is not an option is case of PC reboot (it's not a good idea to store and then restore and summarize previous value with current value)

Comment: So i'am looking for a guaranteed way to know current time since some point in the past which cannot be affected by user and with no need for Internet connection. For example time elapsed since motherboard was manufacruted or something like this. If BIOS time fits these requirements, can you please tell me how can i get it on Windows and Linux?

Comment: When you get the system time in java you are actually querying the bios time (alias system clock). If you can't connect to an external service this is your only option, maybe setting a bios password so that users won't be able to change the setting there, but they can easily change the system date and time in any operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, things don't look good. Considering you aren't allowed to connect to a network, or install hardware that accesses external reliable time sources, maybe the best you can do is rely on a few trusted people.

- Set both the BIOS user password and the BIOS supervisor password. The user password halts the boot process until the password is entered. The supervisor password blocks altering BIOS settings unless the password is known.
- Set the computer to allow only the system administrator (root) to set the time.
- Allow only trusted people to boot the computer. Have them check the system time whenever they boot.
- If you can, use a case that has both a lock and a "case open" switch.

The "case open" switch connects to pins on the motherboard. Set BIOS options to use the "case open" feature. When the case is open, the motherboard detects it, and remembers it. When the computer is booted, an alert is displayed. A password may be required to reset the status.

If you do use a locking case, have a locksmith change the lock. A lot of case locks use the same key, and it's easy to get. They can also be easy to pick.